# How long does process wait for locked file?

Tags: unix, file-locking

If a process in a Unix based OS finds that a file is locked because another process is writing to it, how long does it wait and retry before giving up and returning an error?

Comment: On a Unix OS, a file is not impliclity locked when a process writes to it. You need to lock it explicitly and any process waiting on the lock waits indefinitely unless the process itself choses to timeout.

Comment: Well, there must be something going on to prevent concurrent writing because I have 30 concurrent processes all writing lines to one file, and there are never any lines that have been interrupted by others.

Comment: That really depends on how the processes write the lines. If they use a single blocking write system call per line (or group of lines), then Unix guarantees that the corresponding I/O will complete before another I/O takes place (i.e. a process gets to write a whole line before another process can write another line). This has nothing to do with file locking however, it is simply the way I/O gets queued in the kernel.

Comment: This means that these processes probably use O_APPEND mode; that means that every write is made at the end of the file. As each written line is probably written in a single call, no line overlaps. The file is a kind of log file, isn't it?